# admin panel with multiple user in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

We are making application with having admin panel and under it multiple employees.
   employee only see data and edit and update it.
   I have studied ACL Component but i doesn't understand it  properly, Can we get another
   Link for it.

```
So I have store role admin , employee. 
On user controller when users login it checks whether it is admin or employee 
But it is not working can you suggest whats the problem in code.


  public function beforeFilter()
 {
      parent::beforeFilter();

      $userDetail=$this->Auth->request->data['User'];
      $role = $this->User->findByEmail($userDetail['username']);
         if($role['User']['role'] == "admin") {
      $this->Auth->allow('*');

         }else {
        $this->Auth->allow('add','edit');

        }
```

Comment: You can also follow [TinyAuth](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) and [common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/05/common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions/) for a less controller-invasive approach.

Comment: I can't see any ACl in your code. If you application is simple listen to Fazel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
  public function beforeFilter()
 {
      parent::beforeFilter();

      $role = $this->Auth->user('role');     
         if($role == "admin") {
      $this->Auth->allow('*');
         }else {
        $this->Auth->allow('add','edit');
        } 
}
```

Comment: It helps to explain what you edited and why, so the OP actually learns from it rather than copy/pasting code.

Comment: Its better to confirm first weather his problem is solved or not. His User model is may not like as i suspected or his problem may be on other parts...

Comment: And thank you @Oldskool for reminding me that. I will try to explain my all answer after confirming by the questioner.